# regr.score and r2_score give different values

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn, regression

I am using sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression and using that I calculate the R^2 value as follows

`regr.score(xtest, ytest)`

and I get a score of 0.65

Now, just to compare i used the metric provided by sklearn.metrics.r2_score¶ and I calculate the score as follows

`r2_score(ytest,regr.predict(xtest))`

and I get a score of -0.54

According to the documentation regr.score returns "R^2 of self.predict(X) wrt. y." and this is what I did to calculate R^2 using the metric, but I don't get why the values are so different?

Can anyone help me explain it a bit?

**Update:** As suggested I switched the variables ytest,regr.predict(xtest) in r2_score, but in logistic regression I still get different values. So I updated the question.

Comment: It should be `r2_score(ytest, regr.predict(xtest))` (actual then predicted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get different values because the [`score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score) function in `LogisticRegression` class by default calculates the [**accuracy score**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score). The accuracy score is simply the number of correct predictions divided by the total number of predictions. On the other hand an R2 score is entirely different and you can read more about its mathematics [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I thought the scores are the same for linear and logistic regression and didn't go through the definition.